# URL not reversing in template Django

Tags: python, django

Right now I'm having issues getting the url tag to reverse back to my urls. I'm getting the NoReverseMatch. Specifically its

**Error**

`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'documents' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

I've tried narrowing it down using other url names to reverse, but they also don't work. I'm guessing its something to do with calling the url. Any help will be awesome. If anything else is needed just let me know.

**urls.py**

```
"""urls for vivid"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'website'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',
        views.login_view,
        name='login'),
    url(r'^dashboard/$',
        views.dashboard_view,
        name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^home/$',
        views.home_view,
        name='home'),
    url(r'^addshow/$',
        views.show_add_view,
        name='addshow'),
    url(r'^regis/$',
        views.regis_view,
        name='regis'),
    url(r'^show/(?P<show_id>[0-9]+)/$',
        views.detail_show_view,
        name='detailshow'),
    url(r'^show/(?P<show_id>[0-9]+)/documents$',
        views.documents_view,
        name='documents'),
    url(r'^addcardcomp/$',
        views.add_card_comp,
        name='addcomp'),
    url(r'^homecardcomp/$',
        views.home_card_comp,
        name='homecomp'),

]
```

**templates**

```
<a href="{% url 'documents' show_id=showDocumentID %}"
```

Comment: Is `showDocumentID` a variable? Or do you intend to pass it as a literal string?

Comment: @Chris this is a variable passed in context from the view that is trying to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
<a href="{% url 'website:documents' show_id=showDocumentID %}"
```

Because: <"app_name">: <"url_name"> is better (don't conflict with other app)

Comment: Oh my gosh this is something I've totally run into before, but I totally forgot. Thanks a million friend.